# Call a thickbox alert using php

Tags: php, jquery, alert, thickbox

I'm using thickbox to display alert messages (http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/).  However, the site  explains only to call the alert from clicking a link.  Is there a way to call the function through php somehow?
here's my code:

```
<?php
if ($input!=='submit'){

//put data in databaste
}
else {
//call thickbox alert
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

No. jQuery/Javascript is executed on the client side (your browser) while PHP is executed on the server side.

Maybe if you do an AJAX HTTP Request Post to a php serverside script and get back the response and then do the alert based on that response, you could do what you're wanting. There will definitely need to be client/server communication if you're wanting to apply your PHP business logic with your Javascript.

Comment: @user780483 Err, your question suggests you're lacking some fundamental knowledge first. If I just gave you some example codes, I don't think it's gonna help. Please read HTTP 1.1 Specification in regards to HTTP Requests.

Answer (score 0):

Do it same way as you do it "from clicking a link"

```
echo '<script>$.thickboxAlertFunction("yourtext");</script>';
```

ajax call (expects javascript):

```
$.getScript(
      'yourajax.php', 
      {post:params}, 
      function() {
           /*on success*/
      }
});
```

Comment: where did you get the thickbox alert function?

Comment: I did not get it, you have to replace it with your own function. "However, the site only explains how to call the alert from clicking a link." -> use same function